# minimizing conflicts and maximizing velocity with git

Tags: git, version-control

I got a job in a new company. They use git, but in a way that seems to create unnecessary merge conflicts. Let me explain:

There are 4 devs working on the backend.

There are 2 main working branches:

- staging (almost stable code)
- develop (new features, and bugfix).

Each time a dev works on a new feature, he/she creates a new branch from the HEAD staging branch. Once the job done, he/she merges it into the develop branch and test the new feature (running the code in a docker).

Once in a while, the develop branch (or at least a part of it) is merged into the staging branch, and then tested.

If a bug is found, a bug-fix is done on the staging branch(by creating a bugfix branch from staging and merging it into staging once the fix done) and later cherry-picked to the develop branch. Once the bugs are corrected, a product branch is created from the head of the staging branch. If a bug is once again found, the bugfix is done on this feature branch and then cherry-picked to the develop branch.

They do not use `git tag`.

SO:

- in general the staging is always lagging behind the develop branch (so are the features branches).
- when merge feature branch into develop branch, we always have conflict.
- I'm not sure the incoming changes are not in fact "code regressions"

**What are alternative git workflows to improve the merge experience, and decrease the number of conflicts?**

For example: Today when I compare the develop branch with the staging branch: staging is 152 commits behind (features merged into develop) and 11 commits ahead (all the bugfix done in staging).

Comment: cherry-picking is to ban in a such workflow, branch can be merged into the 2 branches

Comment: Branching off develop does not guarantee there will be no conflicts, but it can eliminate some compared to branching from staging.

Comment: More importantly, the avoidable conflicts have to be resolved by each developer individually.

Comment: Are you looking for a yes/no answer, or do you want solid arguments and concrete examples to use to argue against the current practice?

Comment: @chepner . thanks for your comment. I'm looking more for concrete example. I'm considering myself still a newbie about git . I have been using it in group project for only 3 years. So maybe it's normal if this way to use git is chocking me.

Comment: Possible contradiction here: You stated, "Each time a dev works on a new feature, he/she creates a new branch from the HEAD staging branch. Once the job done, he/she **merges** it into the develop branch" But you also stated, "If a bug is found, a bug-fix is done on the staging branch and later **cherry-picked** to the develop branch." The first one would merge `staging` into `develop` with every feature, and second one cherry-picks instead. There's no way to distinguish "feature" from "bug" except by developer choice. Maybe the first is also cherry-picking (or rebasing) features?

Comment: @TTT I edited my description to be more accurate. Basically we cherry-pick only minor bugfix

Comment: Don't get hung up on that word, it's just telling you Git can't automatically determine the correct result without eyeball assistance. A usual case is, two branches assign a flag bit, where they merge somebody's going to have to fix up any overlap. There's nothing wrong here.

Comment: @ChmickChmick I think the problem here is simply that you sometimes cherry-pick bug fixes into `develop`.  (I'm curious why?) If you merged both features and bug fixes from `staging` into `develop` I suspect some (or most?) of the conflicts would go away.